# Solving the coupled system of ordinary differential equations in MATLAB

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve this system of coupled equations in MATLAB. It will be really helpful if somebody can explain how I can solve this system.

$\ddot{\phi}+\dot{\phi}+g*\phi=\ddot{x}+x+M$

$\ddot{x}+\dot{x}^2+x=-\ddot{\phi}+\phi$

The value of M=1 and the initial conditions for $\dot{\phi}=0$ and $\phi=0$ and $\dot{x}=0$ and $x=0$

Comment: Consider the sum and difference of the equations. That is, solve the linear system in the second derivatives.

Comment: Does the "$*$" mean convolution or just multiplication?